# Serializing to guid types in angular

Tags: angular, typescript, guid, angular-httpclient

Using the guid-typescript package, I wanted to use Guid types in my response model to be more descriptive.

```
import {Guid} from 'guid-typescript';

export class Product {
    id: Guid;
    name: string;
}

...
this.http.get<Product[]>(...);
```

In runtime, however, product.id is a string type, not a Guid type.  How can I inform the angular http library on how to handle these types?

Answer (score 0):

As you might see in the definition of the [Guid class](https://github.com/NicolasDeveloper/guid-typescript/blob/master/lib/guid.ts), internally it's a `string`.
Also Javascript doesn't support `Guid` data types, it's always a `string`.

If you are retrieving a `Guid` from your backend take into account that the library just offers a `class` called ***Guid*** and that the `Guid` datatype is serialized to `string` from your backend.

Comment: Internally it's stored within the class as a string, but it should still be serialized to a Guid object.  Javascript does support Guid data types, that's exactly what the guid class is doing, creating a data type for it.